# Using IIS Express for Local Web Application with Multiple Users

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express

We are going to develop a web application in local network for a company.
We can't use `IIS` because of some limitations, e.g. print document on server side programmatically and GUI processes.
But with `IIS Express` because of running mode, we are able to access all resources that we need, But I'm not sure about performance. I have no idea what will be happened when the Application being used by 70 users. how can i handle this?

Comment: I am not entirely sure this question belongs on Stack Overflow. However, there is no problem with printing on printers on the server with IIS, and why do you want a web server to show dialogs on the web server? IIS Express is not intended for your scenario; IIS is. Official statement: [Internet Information Services (IIS) 7.5 Express is not supported in a production environment](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2562885).

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've had problems with printing on the servers, even I create an external application only for printing purpose, and I execute the application in the web application but it didn't work. If you have a good solution please share it, I did a lot of stuff for this, e.g. changing the application pool, working with IIS_USERS group and etc. but it didn't work.

Comment: @Saman, a web application on IIS in system session won't print, and you should rearchitect the whole system, to be a web application + message queue + a client for printing. The client running in a user's session can subscribe the message queue and print tasks out. Using IIS Express is obvious just a dirty workaround and you should never consider it for production.

Comment: @LexLi I can't use your solution because i need to print document real-time, but I think your solution needs an iterative process on client machine for checking the message queue.

Comment: @SamanGholami it is rather strange that you thought message queue is not `real-time`, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue